# Calculations with UIPickerView and UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am working on an app where the user inputs a textfield value and it is multiplied by a value stored in UIPickerView's didSelectRow method. This is currently working but only when I enter the value and touch/select the picker. How can I have the calculation performed against the selected row as soon as the value is entered into the textfield? Thanks.

```
    class Example2ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var calcLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!

    var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myPicker.delegate = self
        myPicker.dataSource = self
        self.resultsLabel.text = ""
        self.calcLabel.text = ""
        pickerData = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3","Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"]
        myPicker.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print(string)
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func  editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        sender.text = sender.text?.uppercaseString
        inputField.text = sender.text
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
    //UI Pickerview

    // The number of columns of data
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        var multiplicator : Double = 1.0
        if (row == 0)
        {
            resultsLabel.text = "Item 1"
            multiplicator = 1.00
        }
        else if (row == 1)
        {
            resultsLabel.text = "Item 2"
            multiplicator = 2.00
        }
        else if (row == 2)
        {
            resultsLabel.text = "Item 3"
            multiplicator = 3.00
        }
        else if (row == 3)
        {
            resultsLabel.text = "Item 4"
            multiplicator = 4.00
        }
        else if (row == 4)
        {
            resultsLabel.text = "Item 5"
            multiplicator = 5.00
        }
        else if (row == 5)
        {
            resultsLabel.text = "Item 6"
            multiplicator = 6.00
        }

        let result = multiplicator * (inputField.text! as NSString).doubleValue
        calcLabel.text = "Results: \(result)"
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making multiplicator a global var and then you can use it inside the textfield function:

```
 var multiplicator:Double!

@IBAction func editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        sender.text = sender.text?.uppercaseString
        inputField.text = sender.text
        let result = multiplicator * (inputField.text! as NSString).doubleValue
        calcLabel.text = "Results: \(result)"
    }
```

*You can now obviously remove the last 2 lines of code inside the pickerview func*

Comment: The global var is getting me a bit closer to what I'm attempting to do. The issue now is that calcLabel.text is not updating when I change values with the picker, it changes when i click into the inputField.text and then click outside of it. Any other ideas?

Comment: When should calcLabel be updated then? Because I thought you wanted it to be updated as soon as you stopped editing the text.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried something more simple. I made an @IBAction call of the UItextField when edit is done and then I make all my post picker selection there.

```
@IBAction func textField_pickerAction(_ sender: Any) {
let row = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
...
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the global var, I got this working by adding the UIPickerView if statement to it's own function. Now I can call that anywhere I need to.

I'm am updating the calcLabel in real time from the inputField using this:

```
inputField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    pickerFunc()
}
```